# iOS Mobile Web App (via saving page to homescreen) offline availability

Tags: ios, caching, offlineapps

I am trying to make a page mobile web app compatible be available offline on iOS devices. I have added the mobile web app compatible meta tag to the head of the document, and specified a cache.manifest file which contains all of the resources of the page.

I can see that the cache.manifest file is being used authoritatively to load the page resources (namely in the console I can see the resources being saved to the device when I first clear / load the manifest, and on subsequent page loads I can see the 'noupdate' event fires on window.applicationCache.

Despite this, when I turn off WiFi on the iOS device I am currently testing on (iPad 2nd gen, running iOS 8.3) I immediately get a message to say the page could not be loaded because the server cannot be found, the only options on this message are to retry (resulting in the same error) or to close the mobile web app.

Even though I get this error, I can see the page load behind the notification so clearly resources are still being fetched from the application cache, but as I say it appears that the 'no internet' message fires before any sort of application cache interation occurs.

Can anyone please advise as to how I may suppress this 'offline error' message, or fix the cache.manifest so that it works as expected, allowing me to use a mobile web app that is saved to homescreen, without being connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

**NB: iOS Safari and desktop Safari do not support service workers technology and there's no clear roadmap for it.**

Since now in 03/2016 [service workers have better browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers) support (Chrome, Firefox) I would recommend to use this functionality in combination with manifest.json.

What worked for me to provide complete offline experience is [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/). You can set it up as a build task (Gulp, Grunt) or run manually. As a result web app **loads with UI** even case even if the wifi is turned off in advance.

Main part is to add correct static files masks - check *staticFileGlobs* property in `writeServiceWorkerFile` function, smth like this:

```
 staticFileGlobs: [
                rootDir + '/css/**.css',
                rootDir + '/',
                rootDir + 'index.html',
                rootDir + 'index.html/#/home',
                rootDir + 'index.html/#/offline',
                rootDir + '/img/**.*',
                rootDir + '/js/**.js',
                rootDir + '/locales/**.js'
            ],
```

Comment: OP was asking about Mobile Safari, which unfortunately isn't supporting Service Worker any time soon.

Comment: UPDATE: August 3rd, 2017: Apple has changed their status for service workers from "under consideration" to "in development"! Please see [this](https://m.phillydevshop.com/apples-refusal-to-support-progressive-web-apps-is-a-serious-detriment-to-future-of-the-web-e81b2be29676) post for details.